# Copy WordML to Clipboard from Selection

Tags: ms-word, wordml

Is it possible select an area of text in a word 2003/2007 document and then copy the WordML of the selected area to the clipboard? I want to copy the XML format of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the XML via the Range.XML property, then copy THAT to the clipboard as plain text.

Don't think there's any native word function to do that.